# ASP.NET MVC C# Connection String metadata creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, database-connection

Sorry, I have a feeling this is a really basic question, but my connection string to my data source is invalid. I did a bit of trouble shooting and think that I am missing the metadata part of the connectionstring - but I'm not sure where it is/how to create it.

How is how I think it should look

```
<add name="PDCWebEntities" connectionString="metadata=METADATASTRING;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PDC;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And here is where I think the information that needs to be in the metadata string is held:

[image: entities]

It should be noted that the app.config file where the connectionstring is is in the PokemonDayCareSimple.Web project

**Is it possible to make the metadata part of the string from this information?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need metadata for connectionString.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\me\source\repos\MarketplaceMVC\MarketplaceMVC.Web\App_Data\MarketplaceIdentityDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Instead of "AttachDbFilename" you can use also "Initial Catalog".

[image]

In your Context Class you need to add a constructor:

```
public ApplicationContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
{

}
```